# Use regex to replace duplicate phrases

Tags: r, regex, string

I need to parse large data files and for reasons unknown the addresses are sometimes repeated, like this:

```
d<- data.table(name = c("bill", "tom"), address = c("35 Valerie Avenue / 35 Valerie Avenue", "702 / 9 Paddock Street / 702 / 9 Paddock Street"))
```

I have figured out how to de-dupe the easy ones (e.g. "35 Valerie Avenue / 35 Valerie Avenue") with the following:

```
replace.dupe.addresses<- function(x){
  rep_expr<- "^(.*)/(.*)$"
  idx<- grepl("/",x) & (trimws(sub(rep_expr, "\\2", x)) == trimws(sub(rep_expr, "\\1",x)))
  x[idx]<- trimws(sub(rep_expr, "\\1",x[idx]))
  x
}

d[,address := replace.dupe.addresses(address)]
```

But this doesn't work for addresses where the critical '/' is further embedded.  I have tried this as my regex:  `rep_expr<- "^(.*)[:alpha:][:space:]?/(.*)$"`
but this doesn't work.  What regex expression would capture both of these repeating phrases?

Answer (score 3):

See if this works for your dataset

```
library(data.table)

d[, .(name, address = lapply(strsplit(address, " / "), function(x) 
  paste(x[!duplicated(x)], collapse=" / "))), by=.I]
   name                address
1: bill      35 Valerie Avenue
2:  tom 702 / 9 Paddock Street
```

Comment: Thank you both @Andre Wildberg and @zx8754, this does the trick.  Here's my final solution:

`d[, address := sapply(strsplit(address, " / "), function(x) 
  paste(x[!duplicated(x)], collapse=" / ")), by=.I]`

Answer (score 2):

Please check the below code

```r
d %>% separate_rows(address, sep = '\\/') %>% mutate(address=trimws(address)) %>% 
group_by(name, address) %>% slice_head(n=1) %>% group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(address=paste(address, collapse = '/')) %>% slice_head(n=1)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 2
# Groups:   name [2]
  name  address             
  <chr> <chr>               
1 bill  35 Valerie Avenue   
2 tom   702/9 Paddock Street
```

Comment: this is the output I'm looking for.  thanks.  but there must be an easier, more elegant way to get there?  I'm dealing with rather large files and I'm guessing that this would be pretty slow.  but I will give it a go.  thanks again

Comment: actually, after thinking about this a bit more, I have unique records (i.e. rows in the data frame) that share name and address across the file, so I don't think this will work.

Comment: @matto as long as you have unique names, this should work. Please provide bigger example data, maybe 10-20 rows, `dput(head(mydata, 10))`

Answer (score 1):

Split on forward slash, then get *unique* and *paste* it back:

```
sapply(strsplit(d$address, " / ", fixed = TRUE), 
       function(i) paste(unique(i), collapse = "/"))
# [1] "35 Valerie Avenue"    "702/9 Paddock Street"
```

Comment: I like the elegance of this.  Is there a way to retain the '/' so the second address is "702/9 Paddock Street"?  The output posed by @jkatam is what I'm after

Comment: I think the answer by @zx8754 will work a small update us need like `collapse="/"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `regex`

```
gsub("((?:\\S+\\s+/\\s+)?(?:\\S+\\s+){2}\\S+)\\s+/\\s+\\1+", "\\1", d$address)
[1] "35 Valerie Avenue"      "702 / 9 Paddock Street"
```